# How to comment out a Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

```js
some javascript
```

```css
some css
```

```html
some html
```

So you see some snippet above. How to show its structure (raw code)?

`ctrl-k`ing it creates...

```
    some javascript
    some css
    some html
```

Comment: What do you mean "comment out" exactly? Show the raw code?

Comment: @Sha I want to show raw code.

Comment: Why not just remove the "snippet" HTML comments?

Comment: @murgatroid99 yep, I tested it (even removal of a single dash solves it). But what if I want to leave it untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, but I have no idea why ;)

And yes, it is a bit broken as you can't close the tags you open, and you need both of them.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

`<!-- language: lang-js -->

    some javascript

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    some css

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    some html

<!-- end snippet -->`

But you can even write normal text afterwards. `<kbd>` with an escape `\` is magic ;D

basically:

`<kbd>` without `<pre>`, but with `\` to escape the exclamation mark, the first line is not in the block, but the snipped is not valid either.

`<pre>` without `<kbd>`, but with `\` to escape the exclamation mark, the first line is not there (visible) at all.

Comment: @nicael pretty much sums it up ;)